# How to handle field injection to Couchbase repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

In order to add functionality to the couchbase repository I implemented the below class.
Inside this class is another `@componenet` name `extensionHelper`. Since this class is not standard spring bean I can't find a way to inject this field in order to use it in `save()`

Any idea how to inject such a class?

```
public class SimpleCustomRepository<T, ID> extends SimpleCouchbaseRepository<T, ID> {
    @Autowired
    ExtensionHelper extensionHelper;

    public SimpleCustomRepository(CouchbaseEntityInformation<T, String> entityInformation,
                                  CouchbaseOperations couchbaseOperations, Class<?> repositoryInterface) {
        super(entityInformation, couchbaseOperations, repositoryInterface);
    }


    @Override
    public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
        extensionHelper.applyExtensions(entity);
        return super.save(entity);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(T entity) {
        super.delete(entity);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the mappingCouchbaseConverter() method in your configuration class.  Your convert class can extend MappingCouchbaseConverter and override methods as necessary.

```
/* This uses a CustomMappingCouchbaseConverter instead of MappingCouchbaseConverter */
@Override
@Bean(name = "mappingCouchbaseConverter")
public MappingCouchbaseConverter mappingCouchbaseConverter(CouchbaseMappingContext couchbaseMappingContext,
        CouchbaseCustomConversions couchbaseCustomConversions /* there is a customConversions() method bean  */) {
    // MappingCouchbaseConverter relies on a SimpleInformationMapper
    // that has an getAliasFor(info) that just returns getType().getName().
    // Our CustomMappingCouchbaseConverter uses a TypeBasedCouchbaseTypeMapper that will
    // use the DocumentType annotation
    MappingCouchbaseConverter converter = new CustomMappingCouchbaseConverter(couchbaseMappingContext, typeKey());
    converter.setCustomConversions(couchbaseCustomConversions);
    return converter;
}
```